# Ajax request sent to server but returns status code 0

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

My application uses phonegap 1.7.0 and jquery 1.7.1 bundled in an android app. My html contains multiple getJson() calls which run successfully except one when i submit a form.

```
$('#proposalForm1').submit(function(event){
    var formInput = $(this).serialize();
    $('#loader').show();
    $.getJSON("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8282/Service004/user/jsProposalPage1.action",  formInput,function(data){
    $('#loader').hide();
    if(data.serviceErrorMsg == ""){
      window.location.replace("proposalDisplay.html");
    }
    else{
      alert(data.serviceErrorMsg);
    }
}).error(function(xhr){
        $('#loader').hide();
        alert(xhr.status);
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Please try again later!',  // message
            doNothing,         // callback
            'Server Unavailable',            // title
            'Exit'                  // buttonName
            );
    });
    return false;
});
```

Sometimes it works, but mostly it returns error code 0.The app server to which the request is made receives the request successfully and calls a webs service. The response from the web service is received by the app server successfully, but the phonegap app reports a staus code 0. Can anyone please help me? The same problem exists when the app is bundled for blackberry using Web works and not phone gap. Tested on Android 2.3.3 and Blackberry 9300 curve.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I had this exact same problem before while running jQuery 1.7.1 and Phonegap. It appears to happen when the server's response isnt fast enough. I repaired it using a delay, but solved it by using jQuery 1.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend switching your $.getJSON call to a full $.ajax() call and setting the timeout to something a little longer. It's probably due to the fact the your webservice takes too long to reply.

If this doesn't work, you may need to configure your app server to wait to reply until it has the response. Status code 0 means that "the response was empty, (as not even headers were returned). This means the connection was accepted and then closed gracefully (TCP FIN)."

There are a number of things which could cause this, most likely a timeout in your case, but a firewall could also be the culprit, (less likely, as the app server was working for other requests).

Comment: Thanks, i've implemented the full $.ajax() method and its error returns a Status Code of 504, most likely indicating a firewall issue.The other requests don't have to wait more than a few seconds.I have contacted the system administrators, hopefully they would fix it.